# Writing "$\nabla f$" or "$\operatorname{grad} f$"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

When hand-writing the gradient of $f$ as "$\nabla f$" or "grad $f$", is it necessary to indicate that it is a vector using the usual vector markings (cap, arrow, wavy line, etc.)?

Comment: Writing $\nabla f$ or ${\rm grad}\, f$ is sufficient. Avoid "vector markings" and use bold face if you want to enhance the fact that you are talking about a vector here; like ${\bf x}=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$.

Comment: You use bold face in hand writing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be considered obligatory to write, for example  $\vec{a}$ or $\mathbf{a}$, when you're writing in a context in which vectors and vector-valued functions are generally written that way.  But that is not always done.  The style should be consistent throughout the document.

However, notice that the $f$ in $\nabla f$ is scalar-valued.  The expression $\nabla f$ is vector-valued, and that is indicated by the meanings of the symbols.